# Remove regex pattern from string and store in csv

Tags: regex, csv, python-3.x

I am trying to clean up a CSV by using regex. I have accomplished the first part which extracts the regex pattern from the address table and writes it to the street_numb field. The part I need help with is removing that same pattern from the street field so I only end up with the following (i.e., Steinway St, 31 St, 82nd Rd, and 19th St) stored in the street field. Hence these values would be removed (-78, -45, -35, -54) from the street field.

```
b    street_numb     street            address              zipcode
1    246             FIFTH AVE         246 FIFTH AVE        11215
2    30 -78          -78 STEINWAY ST   30 -78 STEINWAY ST   11016
3    25 -45          -45 31ST ST       25 -45 31ST ST       11102
4    123 -35         -35 82ND RD       123 -35 82ND RD      11415
5    22 -54          -54 19TH ST       22 -54 19TH ST       11105
```

Sample Data (above)

```
import csv
import re
path = '/Users/darchcruise/Desktop/bldg_zip_codes.csv'
with open(path, 'rU') as infile, open(path+'out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
   fieldnames = ['b', 'street_numb', 'street', 'address', 'zipcode']
   readablefile = csv.DictReader(infile)
   writablefile = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
   for row in readablefile:
       add = re.match(r'\d+\s*-\s*\d+', row['address'])
       if add:
            row['street_numb'] = add.group()
            # row['street'] = remove re.string (add.group()) from street field
            writablefile.writerow(row)
       else:
            writablefile.writerow(row)
```

What code in line 12 (# remove re.string from row['street']) could be used to resolve my issue (removing  -78, -45, -35, -54 from the street field)?

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capturing group with `findall` like this

```
[x for x in re.findall("(\d+\s*(-\s*\d+\s+)?)((\w|\s)+)", row['address'])][0][0]-->gives street number 
[x for x in re.findall("(\d+\s*(-\s*\d+\s+)?)((\w|\s)+)", row['address'])][0][2]-->gives address
```

Comment: That would not work in line 12.  It would have to be something that looked like this: `row['street'] = code`.  That way the results would be written to the file in the line below (line13).

Comment: isnt `row[street] = [x for x in re.findall("(-\d+\s+)?((\w|\s)+)", "FIFTH ST")][0][1]` working

Comment: Part of that line worked. But it is replacing all the street field with the name "Fifth St". I want to bring over the value from the address field (with the regex removed).

Comment: Should not be this: `6 , 25 -40, FIFTH ST,  25 -40 14TH STREET, 11102`.    It should be `6 , 25 -40,  14TH STREET,  25 -40 14TH STREET, 11102`

Comment: can you give an example from the data given by you in your question

Comment: Well, what code can I substitute in its place, so that the real values from `street['address']` come through?

Comment: you mean `row['address']`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105717/discussion-between-rock321987-and-user3062459).

Comment: If I replace `FIFTH ST` with `row['address']` i.e.  `row['street'] = [x for x in re.findall("(-\d+\s+)?((\w|\s)+)", row['address'])][0][1]`  I get `7, 125 -10, 125, 125 -10 QUEENS BOULEVARD,  11415` which is incorrect. Should be `7, 125 -10, QUEENS BOULEVARD, 125 -10 QUEENS BOULEVARD, 11415`